# RPSystemBroadcastPickerView - how can I pass data in extension context to RPBroadcastSampleHandler

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I have a react native project where I have to broadcast my phone screen(even on background) to a room (using twilio).
I am using RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to show the broadcast picker and a sampleHandler to handle the frames. I already have access tokens in my hosting app - how can i pass the data in extenstion context to SampleHandler?

Comment: did you find any solution?